# Timer in java, cant get the player to flinch 3 seconds

Tags: java, timer

I'm trying to make my player flinch when he gets attacked.
I cant get the timer right, I disable the collision when the mobs touch the player but I cant able the collision between the player and the mobs after 3 seconds. Cant get it right.. Help please :/

code

```
            if(flinching == false) {
             if(tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.FirstMob) {
                currenthealth = health;
                if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                    currenthealth = health;
                    health -= 5;
                    flinching = true;
                    long current_frame_time = System.nanoTime()/1000000000; //seconds
                    long last_frame_time = current_frame_time;
                    long current_frame_time2 = System.nanoTime()/1000000000;
                    while(current_frame_time2 - last_frame_time != 3) 
                        current_frame_time2 = System.nanoTime()/1000000000;
                    if(current_frame_time2 - last_frame_time == 3)
                        flinching = false;
                    System.out.println(flinching);
                    System.out.println(health);
                    if(health == 0) {
                        alive = 0;
                        if(alive == 0){ 
                            alive = 1;
                            handler.removeObject(this);
                            handler.restartLevel();
                            handler.respwan();
                        }       
                    }
                }
```

Comment: "long current_frame_time = System.nanoTime()/1000000000; //seconds
                        long last_frame_time = current_frame_time;
                        long current_frame_time2 = System.nanoTime()/1000000000;
                        if(current_frame_time2 - last_frame_time == 3)" This is very very improbable to set flinching to flase. Those instructions are executed right after another. How do you expect them to be _exactly_ 3 secs apart?

Comment: I just dont know how to do it.
I've put it into a while loop until current_frame_time2 - last_frame_time == 3 but the game freezes this 3 seconds

Comment: Anyone? Please help :/